# Why my PHP doesn't run the same command as specified in cmd?

Tags: php, windows, exec, stdout, wampserver

I'm using a windows machine.
When I run this command in cmd it works fine.

```
C:\wamp\www\upload\cprogram.exe > output.txt
```

But when I write the same command in my php it shows

> "> not recognised as an internal or external command"

My php code :

```
$exepath="C:\wamp\www\upload\cprogram.exe";

$outputpath="C:\wamp\www\upload\output.txt";
exec("$exepath > $outputpath");
```

Please tell me how can i send my executed C program output a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please tell me how can i send my executed C program output a file?

There are many ways that you can write the output of your command to a file using php.

In your example it doesnt work due to the use of concatenation. This should work better:

```
exec($exepath.' > '.$outputpath);
```

Another option would be to use the [`shell_exec`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) command instead:

```
$exepath="C:\wamp\www\upload\cprogram.exe";
$outputpath="C:\wamp\www\upload\output.txt";
shell_exec ($exepath ." > ". $outputpath);
```

Or just use the [`system`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) command and write the output to a file yourself:

```
$exepath="C:\wamp\www\upload\cprogram.exe";
$outputpath="C:\wamp\www\upload\output.txt";
system($exepath, $return);
$fp = fopen($outputpath, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $return);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you last part did the trick. But I've to pass return value instead of return status. So I did little changes to the code. $result=system($exepath,$return); fwrite($fp,$result);